# KIVY language: multiple commands in a single line

Tags: python, syntax, kivy, kivy-language

I have to do:

```
TextInput:
    on_text: something ; something_else
```

How can I perform this without getting errors in kv language?

Comment: Define a function (in python) which you then call in kv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add more `on_text` bindings, line by line:

```
TextInput:
    on_text: something
    on_text: something_else
```

But I'd prefer binding custom function call, because I'm not sure order of execution is always the same with the above example. Something like this:

```
MyTextInput:
    on_text: self.custom_function()
```

and in python:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def custom_function(self):
        something()
        something_else()
```

Comment: This appears to be partially incorrect, multiple on_text do not seem to work. However according to this... https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html?highlight=lang#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords You can have multiple lines so long as they do not change the indent level and have \ at the end of the line

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Jim Morris, the (currently accepted) answer by kilbee is not correct and "feels" quiet dirty (in both variations).

The following works for me and "feels" like a clean solution:

```
TextInput:
    on_text:
        something
        something_else
```

Comment: Works `ubuntu 18.04; python 3.6.7; kivy 1.10.1`